# TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: django-views

```
 File "/home/vikas/Desktop/mia/accounts/views.py", line 37, in login
 redirect_to = request.GET.get[redirect_field_name, '']
 redirect_to = request.GET.get[redirect_field_name, '']
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, I assume you want to get the value of `redirect_field_name` or an empty string if it is not found.

The thing is that you need to call the function `get` from the `request.GET` dictionary, and you're currently mixing concepts (you are using `[]` instead of `()`).

Try that:
`redirect_to = request.GET.get(redirect_field_name, '')`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your view is not able to fetch the value of your redirect_field_name.

Add this function in your models.py file in class where you have defined this table.

`def __getitem__(self):
        return self.redirect_field_name`